# Why I am not getting any output when I run the program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, python-3.6

This is a small vaccation trip calculator program. I am here using function so anyone help me out to get the output. I don't understand where i am getting stuck.

## Hotel Cost Per nights :

```
> def hotel_cost(days):   return 140 * days Flight cost for different
> cities:  def plane_ride_cost(city):    if city == "Charlotte":
>     return 183   elif city == "Tampa":
>     return 220   elif city == "Pittsburgh":
>     return 222   elif city == "Los Angeles":
>     return 475
> 
# Per Day Car Ride cost: 
> def rental_car_cost(days):   
>      per_day_cost = 40 * days   
>       if days >= 7:
>     per_day_cost = per_day_cost - 50
>     return per_day_cost   elif days >=3:
>     per_day_cost = per_day_cost - 20
>     return per_day_cost   else:
>     return per_day_cost
> 
#Total trip Cost: 
> def trip_cost(city,days):       
> total = rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days - 1)+
> plane_ride_cost(city)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only returning stuff, you need to print out your returned variable, e. g. `print (total)` at the end of your `trip_cost()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Now it doesn't produce errors and you have to print the results or make a new function that prints the results.

```
#Hotel Cost Per nights :
def hotel_cost(days): return 140 * days
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte": return 183
    elif city == "Tampa": return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh": return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles": return 475

#Per Day Car Ride cost:
def rental_car_cost(days):
    per_day_cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        per_day_cost = per_day_cost - 50
        return per_day_cost
    elif days >=3:
        per_day_cost = per_day_cost - 20
        return per_day_cost
    else: return per_day_cost

#Total trip Cost:
def trip_cost(city,days):
    total = rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days - 1)+ plane_ride_cost(city)
    print(total)
```

Comment: What did you change? Can you update your answer to call that out?

Answer (score 0):

**Have a look on this code:**

```
#Hotel Cost Per nights :
def hotel_cost(days): return 140 * days
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte": return 183
    elif city == "Tampa": return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh": return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles": return 475

#Per Day Car Ride cost:
def rental_car_cost(days):
    per_day_cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        per_day_cost = per_day_cost - 50
        return per_day_cost
    elif days >=3:
        per_day_cost = per_day_cost - 20
        return per_day_cost
    else: return per_day_cost

#Total trip Cost:
def trip_cost(city,days):
    total = rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days - 1)+ plane_ride_cost(city)
    print(total)
```